# Asymmetric peak fit in python

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am trying to find the peak of my data set by fitting it to a Lorentzian (more specifically I have to find at what value of the B-field the peak occurs). However, what follows the peak is not symmetric and definitely not linear so I am having trouble getting a good fit. This is what I have tried:

```
import numpy
import pylab
from scipy.optimize import leastsq # Levenberg-Marquadt Algorithm #

def lorentzian(x,p):
   numerator =  (p[0]**2 )
   denominator = ( x - (p[1]) )**2 + p[0]**2
   y = p[2]*(numerator/denominator)+p[3]*(x-p[0])+p[4]
   return y

def residuals(p,y,x):
   err = y - lorentzian(x,p)
   return err


a = numpy.loadtxt('QHE.dat')
x = a[int(len(a)*8.2/10):,0]
y = a[int(len(a)*8.2/10):,1]


# initial values #
p = [0.4,1.2,1.5,1,1]  # [hwhm, peak center, intensity] #
pbest = leastsq(residuals,p,args=(y,x),full_output=1)
best_parameters = pbest[0]

# fit to data #
fit = lorentzian(x,best_parameters)
peaks.append(best_parameters)

pylab.figure()
pylab.plot(x,y,'wo')
pylab.plot(x,fit,'r-',lw=2)
pylab.xlabel('B field', fontsize=18)
pylab.ylabel('Resistance', fontsize=18)
pylab.show()`
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how to handle this?

Edit:

[Here is the data file I am trying to fit. The goal is to find the minimum.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1UP42H44bf-Q0ZuOGhub1FBWUE)

Comment: Would you please post the data or a link to same?  I would like to give it a try - James

Comment: Sorry for the delay. If you still want to try, I posted the link to the datafile.

Comment: 0
down vote
 

Thank you for the raw sata. When I look at a simple scatterplot of all data, I can clearly see two peaks. Yet your code slices the entire raw data into an area that does not correspond to either of the peaks seen on the scatterplot, making a peak fit difficult. Is the data slicing correct?

Comment: I realized the data set was a different one when I made the code, I apologize for that. But playing around with the slicing should make it right. Eventually I used a function like Const. - Lorentzian and flipped the data, which made a better fit. Still, I am working on detecting the trough so that I don't have to do it manually for each data set.